International Telephone Input for Contact Form 7 in Popup Window
I use this plugin International Telephone Input for Contact Form 7. It works great on desktop just on page or popup window, but on mobile devices phone dropdown menu on popup doesn't work at all. What is the problem it might be? With popup or with Phone Plugin? For popup windows I use PopUp Maker plugin.

Easy way to find out: try the form outside the popup. If the dropdown works outside of the popup on mobile then you likely have a problem with the popup plugin. If it doesn't work on mobile then the problem is the dropdown itself. In any case, you'll want to reach out to the plugin's support forum, Stack Overflow isn't the right place for support questions like this one.
